# regular expression issue in django urls.py

Tags: python, regex, django, web

I am serving static files in Django locally through their simple server. I have the following line included in my urls.py:

```
    static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

(Bonus points to anyone who can tell me why this isn't automatically checked by the url resolver. I have django.contrib.staticfiles install and have DEBUG set to True).

If we take a peek at the implementation of static, we find a really simple function:

```
if not settings.DEBUG or (prefix and '://' in prefix):
    return []
elif not prefix:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Empty static prefix not permitted")
return patterns('',
    url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % re.escape(prefix.lstrip('/')), view, kwargs=kwargs),
)
```

the last line ends up getting added to my url patterns.

When I run the web server, it doesn't properly serve files from that STATIC_ROOT. Here is an example:

1. I type the following into url into my browser:     localhost:8000/Users/nick/Documents/coding/sparestub/static_root/contact/js/contact.js
2. Here is the server response:

   ```
   Request Method: GET
   Request URL:        http://localhost:8000/Users/nick/Documents/coding/sparestub/static_root/contact/js/contact.js

   Using the URLconf defined in sparestub.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
   ^$ [name='homepage']
   ^registration/
   ^Users\/nick\/Documents\/coding\/sparestub\/sparestub\/\.\.\/static_root\/(?P<path>.*)$
   ```

Notice that we are searching the STATIC_ROOT correctly.  If I copy and paste the url into bash, it finds the directory:

```
    Nick-MacBook-Pro:Documents nick$ cd /Users\/nick\/Documents\/coding\/sparestub\/sparestub\/\.\.\/static_root\/
    Nick-MacBook-Pro:static_root nick$ pwd
    /Users/nick/Documents/coding/sparestub/static_root
    Nick-MacBook-Pro:static_root nick$ cd /Users\/nick\/Documents\/coding\/sparestub\/sparestub\/\.\.\/static_root\/
    Nick-MacBook-Pro:static_root nick$ pwd
    /Users/nick/Documents/coding/sparestub/static_root
    Nick-MacBook-Pro:static_root nick$ cd contact/js
    Nick-MacBook-Pro:js nick$ ls
    contact.js
```

And notice that it contains /contact/js/contact.js!!

And seeing at contact/js/contact.js matches the RE pattern (?P.*), I expect this entire thing to work.  Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: Normally I would not expect to a URL like `localhost/Users/actual/system/path/...`.  Are you sure you're setting the URL to the proper *server* path?  By default this would be `localhost/static`

Comment: Are you familiar with Django? This is just for local development, and the files are just being served off the file system. I think I figured out what was wrong.  Django didn't like the sparestub\/\.\.\/static_root.  it seems like the "\." through it off. When i define the url in absolute terms, Everything works. I would guess that this is a bug in Django

Comment: I am familiar with it, though it's been so long since I've used the development server that I didn't realise it would serve files from *anywhere*.  It's probably better practice to set up `STATIC_URL` properly, though.

Comment: yeah, it worked beautifully when STATIC_URL is set up more traditonally